# Can't add multiple enemies in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a Space Invaders like game and I recently got an error saying that "i" is undefined, when I stored the enemy's variables into lists in order add more enemies to the game trough a "for i in range(num_of_enemies) loop. I'm using Python 3.8 and PyCharm. I said everything right now but I have to keep writing in order to be able to post this.

```
import pygame
import random
import math

# Initiate pygame
pygame.init()

# Display the game window
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

# Enemies
enemySprite = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change = []

num_of_enemies = 6

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemySprite.append(pygame.image.load('enemy.png'))
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0, 736))
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50, 150))
    enemyX_change.append(4)
    enemyY_change.append(20)

def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemySprite[i], (x, y))

def isCollision(enemyX, enemyY, bulletX, bulletY):
    distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(enemyX - bulletX, 2)) + (math.pow(enemyY - bulletY, 2)))
    if distance < 27:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Game Loop
running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):

    # Enemies movement
    enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]

    # Prevents the enemies from going off the border
    if enemyX[i] <= 0 or enemyX[i] >= 736:
        enemyX_change[i] *= -1
        enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

        # Collision
        collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
        if collision:
            bulletY = 480
            bullet_state = 'ready'
            score += 1
            print(score)
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)

        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to the enemy logic in the `for` loop, which iterates the enemies, rather than the main application loop.
Furthermore `bulletX`, `bulletY` are not defined. You have to define this variables before the main application loop.
Clear the display or draw the background image before you draw the enemies and draw the enemies in a separate loop.
Use [`pygame.time.Clock()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) to control the frames per second.

```py
bulletX, bulletY = 0, 0

# Game Loop
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):

      # Enemies movement
      enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]

      # Prevents the enemies from going off the border
      if enemyX[i] <= 0 or enemyX[i] >= 736:
          enemyX_change[i] *= -1
          enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

          # Collision
          collision = isCollision(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], bulletX, bulletY)
          if collision:
              bulletY = 480
              bullet_state = 'ready'
              score += 1
              print(score)
              enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
              enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)

    # draw background image
    # [...]

    # d raw enemies
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

    # update display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Now I got another bug. Because of the `screen.fill(0)` instruction, the background image (which I didn't added to the code on this post) is missing, and because of that too all the characters are moving super fast.

Comment: @AmanoSkullGZ I've extended the answer. Remove `screen.fill` and `blit` the background instead . Use `pygame.time.Clock()` to control the frames per second.